# not equal to not working in postgresql query

Tags: node.js, postgresql, postman

```
if (req.body.positionDetails && req.body.positionDetails.length > 0) {
 let total = req.body.positionDetails.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < total; i++) {
  db.query('SELECT * FROM position WHERE position <> $1',[req.body.positionDetails[i].position],function(err,p) {
    console.log(p.rows)
  });
 }
}
```

It is selecting all the values from the database without checking the condition. How to solve this??
data is like 
`"positionDetails":[{"position":"manager"},{"position":"developer"}]` and it is from postman.

Comment: Can you show us some data and/or what the raw query you intend to run looks like?

Comment: my question is edited please check.

Answer (score 0):

Your prepared statement looks off to me.  Try using `?` as a placeholder for the position in your query.

```
db.query(
    'SELECT * FROM position WHERE position <> ?', [req.body.positionDetails[i].position],
    function(err, p) {
        console.log(p.rows)
});
```

If this fixes the problem, then I suggest that you were comparing the `position` against the literal string `$1`, and every comparison failed resulting in every record appearing in the result set.

Comment: This sounds like maybe an error having to do with the loop in `i`.  Maybe you should also post that code.

Comment: I don't know why it's still failing, but I think you can even get rid of the loop entirely.